# Extracting values from a complex MLR model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, modeling

I am looking to extract values for a dependent variable "y" from a MLR model ("`lm_complex`"). The independent variable "x" is continuous, with a range of 40-70. The model also contains four categorical covariates, a quadratic term, and an interaction term. I am looking for a function that can tell me where the line of best fit for my model passes through "y" at a given value of "x" (specifically, 40 or 70).

Here is a simple reprex of `lm_complex`:

```
df<-
  data.frame(
    x=c(40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70),
    y=c(20,29,19,14,17,22,26,22,15,28,25),
    a=c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A"),
    b=c("I","II","I","II","I","II","I","II","I","II","I"),
    c=c("One","Two","One","Two","One","Two","One","Two","One","Two","One"),
    d=c("0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0")
  )

lm_complex<-
  lm(
    y~
      poly(x,2)+
      a*poly(x,2)+
      a+
      b+
      c+
      d,
    data=df
  )

summary(lm_complex)
```

I understand how to calculate the value of "y" when "x" is 40 or 70 in a very simple MLR model with one continuous independent variable and one categorical variable, e.g.,:

```
lm_simple<-
  lm(
    y~
      x+
      a,
    data=df
      
  )

summary(lm_simple)
```

[image: Summary of lm_simple]

The calculation would be

14.667+(0.103 * 40)+([0 or 1] * 2.667)
-OR-
14.667+(0.103 * 70)+([0 or 1] * 2.667)

But in `lm_complex`, I am not sure how to calculate it. My actual dataset also contains ~500k observations, and one categorical variables with >100 factor levels, so I cannot reasonably calculate them from visual analysis of the `summary(lm_complex)` output, as is possible with `summary(lm_simple)`.

Specifically, I need the "y" values for `lm_complex` when "x" is 40 for both factor levels of "a", and I also need to find the corresponding values for "x"=70.

I have used `predict()` before, but only to make predictions for data outside of the original dataset, which is not what I want to do here. I do not want to lose half of my participants by making a training and validation models, for instance. However, `predict()` might be the correct function for this problem, if used correctly? That being said, all of the questions/documentation that I can find for `predict()` seem to focus on using it to predict values in a novel dataset, so perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree with that function.

If anyone has any thoughts then I would be very grateful to hear them.

Thank you.

Comment: Predict can predict anything you put into it (figuratively speaking), it doesn't have to be "outside" your training data.

Comment: At which values of the other variables would you like your predictions to be calculated? You know the values of some features for which you want predictions made, but those predictions will vary depending on the values of the other features.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: @Dave I am not sure, as on further reflection I think that the number of Lines of Best Fist will be a * b * c * d, i.e., one for each possible combination of factors (in this case, it would be well over 1000). Is this correct? In this case, if I just want to find the predictions for both levels of "a" (i.e., two lines of best fit total), will I basically have to set a fixed value for "b", "c", and "d", or maybe just exclude them from the model? As you can tell, I am not used to working with complex MLR models so their interpretation is not intuitive to me. Thanks Dave